# Journey not firing when adding filters

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, filters, entry-criteria

I am trying to set up a journey that our patients start when their opportunity enters a certain stage. However, I want it filtered to a specific list of treatment options. When I leave off the filters and just use the entry criteria "Opportunity:StageName EQUALS In Discussion" people are entered into it just fine, but as soon as I add the filters to the specific treatment plan options, my entries are always zero.
Any insight would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the journey is injecting prior to adding that additional criteria, then we can rule out the Marketing Cloud Connect integration being an issue in the sense that it isn't communicating between the clouds. Can you confirm how you are updating this related object field to meet entry criteria? Is this being done manually or is it done via an automated process? If automated, it is possible that the JB Flow is running prior to the field being updated, which will prevent it from being injected. If the value already is populated on an already created record when you activate the journey, then it will not inject unless you update that field.

If you are updating this field manually, I would run Debug logs to see if there is any additional details that you can find. It might also be a good idea to create a support case with Marketing Cloud Support.

With integrated Journey Builder injection issues, there can be multiple things that can prevent injections, so unfortunately there isn't always a clear cut answer. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the information! We are updating all fields manually at this time, and the planned treatment field is updated prior to the stage being changed. I will run the logs and see if I can gain any further info.